# SQL Query to calculate On-Peak/ Off-peak total for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Could someone help me with a SQL query to calculate the total on-peak and off-values for a month as well as the Max/highest on-peak/off-peak hourly value for that month.

On a daily basis I store the hourly values of the meter in a SQL table.

**On-Peak**

- Summer: Apr-Oct hours(7-22) on weekdays (M-F)
- Winter: Nov-Mar hours(8-23) on weekdays (M-F)

**Off-Peak**

- Summer: Apr-Oct hours(0-6,23,24); Weekends (Saturday & Sunday) ; all public holidays during those months are to be considered as off peak
- Winter: Nov-Mar hours(0-7,24);Weekends (Saturday & Sunday); all public holidays during those months as to be considered as off peak

Here is the DB Table Structure:

```
HourId         - Uniqueidentifier
CustomerName   - nvarchar(50)
Readingdate    - datetime
IntegratedHour - TinyInt
Load           - decimal(18,4)
Generation     - Decimal (18,4)
LastModified   - Datetime
ModifiedBy     - nvarchar(50)
```

Comment: I would implement a scalar function to detect on/off peak. The trick is you need a calendar table for the holidays. Then you can tun that on your table and group it.

Comment: Tom, thank you for your response. Appreciate if  you could explain me in detail so that i will request the client to add/create a table to solve the above problem.

Comment: Tom, as you mentioned about i tried the query again its not showing like you mentioned above. Here is what i am looking to bring in the result. Month|OnPeak|TotalLoad(OnPeak+OffPeak)|OnPeakTotal for the month|OffPeakTotalforthe month|MaxPeak|MinPeak. I am getting all the values except the totalLoad which is the sum of (onPeak+OffPeak for the selected month).

Comment: TotalLoad in your example is the sum of Peak and next row is the sum of offpeak. with your result i need a separate column that gives me the total of both onpeak+offpeak. Separate column that shows the TotalLoadOnpeak + TotalLoadOffPeak = SumofOnpeak&Offpeak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code, explanation below:

```
declare @start_date date = '1 Feb 2014'
declare @end_date date = '31 Jul 2014'

with ReadingsMonth as
(
  select *, month(ReadingDate) as [month] from readings r
  where ReadingDate between @start_date and @end_date
)
, ReadingMonthPeak as
(
  select r.[month], r.[load], 
    case
      when h.[date] is not null then 0  -- holiday
      when datepart(dw, r.ReadingDate) in (1,7) then 0  -- weekend
      when (r.[month] between 4 and 10) and (IntegratedHour < 7 or IntegratedHour > 22) then 0 -- summer
      when (r.[month] < 4 or r.[month] > 10) and (IntegratedHour < 8) then 0 -- winter
      else 1
    end as onpeak
  from ReadingsMonth r
  left join holidays h on h.[date] = r.ReadingDate
)
select [month], [onpeak], sum([load]) as TotalLoad, max([load]) as MaxLoad
from ReadingMonthPeak
group by [month], [onpeak]
order by [month], [onpeak]
```

First CTE just adds month. The second calculates on/off peak hours based on your rules. Note that you need a table with all holiday dates. In final select you just group and sum it by month and on/off peak flag. Check out the fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a87240/5/0.

Comment: Tom, Thank you so so much for this query with explanation. One more question how do i get the total of both onpeak and offpeak value in a separate column.How to implement date range where in i select particular date range and customer.

Comment: I would add the additional filters to the first CTE, simply add a where clause there and filter by date or customer based on your parameters. To show on/off peak as columns use PIVOT. I updated the answer with former but you need to figure the latter on yourself as I'm no expert in PIVOT.

Comment: Tom, how do i add the sum off both onpeak & off values as separate column in the code. For exam: in your example for January On Peak value is 205.8313   and OffPeak value is 159.2245 how do i add to get the total as (365.0558) = 205.8313+159.2245   in a separate column for that selected month

Comment: @ted I didn't see your other comments. Did you PIVOT the totals/max/mins? Then adding this up to a grand total shouldn't be a problem. If you are still stuck try to formulate that as a new question. I believe the original question is answered.